# Deleting the zip folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a zip folder and normal folder in same path.
I need to delete the zip folder only from that path

[image]

I tried using this script:

```
$TestPath='D:\RAW\St\Documentum\2021-10-12\VPA_IMAGES'
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip | `
  ForEach-Object { if ($TestPath $_.BaseName) {
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $_.BaseName }
  }
```

It is not removing that zip folder. How can I delete that zip folder?

Comment: Replace `$TestPath $_.BaseName` with `Test-Path $_.BaseName`

Comment: The term 'Test-Path=D:\RAW\St\Documentum\2021-10-12\VPA_IMAGES' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: No one said anything about `=` :) `if(Test-Path $_.BaseName){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$TestPath='E:\testing'
Get-ChildItem -Path $TestPath -Filter '*.zip' | Remove-Item
```

[image]

Comment: Above PowerShell command will delete all the Zip folders in the testing Folder. Also don't forgot to mark it as answer, if this is useful